# Regex match a-Z0-9

Tags: .net, regex

Assume that we have

```
function test1(
function           t2 (
function test3asdfasd                            (
function(
function (
```

the functions name accept only a-Z0-9 then have Left Parathensis
I would like match the 3 first but no the 2last on CSharp

thanks

Comment: [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net), and thus the .NET Regex implementation, says that `[a-Z]` is a syntax error (probably because that would be an empty range).

Comment: Can a `function` name start with a DIGIT ? *justathought*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following in .NET:

```
(?<=function\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\()
```

- `(?<=function\s*)`: Makes sure whatever is matches is preceded by the literal string `function` then zero or more `\s*` spaces.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`: This is used to match the function name.
- `(?=\s*\()`: This is used to make sure the string matched by the previous part is actually a function name by making sure it is followed by an open parentheses `(`.

In C# you can use the [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) method like this:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=function\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\()";
string sentence = "function hello()";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                       match.Value, match.Index);
```

**EDIT:** In Notepad++ You need to change the expression to this one:

```
function\s*\K[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\()
```

If your function names can contain underscores `_` then include the underscore in the character class like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
          ^
```

**EDIT 2:** If my last comment is correct then you can modify the expressions just a little bit like this:

```
 (?<=^\s*function\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\()
```

and in Notepad++:

```
 ^\s*function\s*\K[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\s*\()
```

[RegexHero Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=07772910-e43b-4268-8b43-03d3ab7fa09b)

Comment: nah, your regex match only the 1st and left the others, imagine is 2000lines some of them starting (I forgot to point this) as the samples I posted (starting means also \t and spaces before), I didnt try nothing before, because everytime I tried regex I cant do anything... :( sorry

Comment: @Zakari I have edited my regular expression and it matches all you want, check the demo link I posted.

Comment: this is what im using again got only the 1st one

Comment: @Zakari Did you check the demo, Also how are you doing it in C# code. Can you edit to your question to show your code please ?

Comment: check @:http://i.imgur.com/ozjnnnZ.png  so my fault also underscore! you are right thanks!!!!

Comment: @Zakari Why have you tagged your regular expression with .NET while you are using Notepad++, the regular expression I gave you doesn't work in any other language but in .NET. I will edit my answer to give you another expression which works with Notepad++ too.

Comment: yes mate, csharp, I used notepad++  to show you the shot... thanks again

Comment: you know what? it doesnt verify if is any character before 'function' :(

Comment: @Zakari What do you mean, can you explain more ?

Comment: if is 'word function test1(' dont match it, now is added to matches I would like 'function' to be the first word in the line (means can be \t and spaces before, that is acceptable otherwise dont match it) (read also in this section the 1st^ reply I have done

Comment: @Zakari Let me see if I understand correctly. So you only want to match `function` if it is preceded by just spaces or tabs and you don't want to match it when there something else before it.

Comment: also should be like "\bfunction\b" to match complete word right?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
function\s+[\w\d]+\s*\(
```

Good Luck!